# Why can we read any char in this allocated pointer and not write to it?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm still a newbie to **C**

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(512);
str = "hello";
*(str) = 'H'; // Segmentation fault
```

I get a `Segmentation fault` on the third line trying to **set** an character

I know that `str` is a **pointer** to the **first** `char` and I can **printf** it

```
printf("%c\n", *str); // Output: h
```

Well, Is it in **Read-Only** memory? I'm not sure why that happened but I can change the **whole** pointer just like I did

```
str = "hello";
```

I can do that

```
char** str = (char**)malloc(512*sizeof(char*));
*str = "hello";
*(str+1) = "Yo!";
//*(str) = 'H';
printf("%s\n", *(str)); // Prints: hello
printf("%s\n", *(str+1)); // Prints: Yo!
```

from the last code, I can do this and still the same

```
str[0] = "hello";
str[1] = "Yo!";
```

The reason is that it's an **array of pointers** after all, I'm just changing that **pointer** like in the first code, with some **index**

and the reason why `*(str+1) = "Yo!";` works, I'm incrementing the **address** or the 0 **index** of `char*` which gives me the address of the next adjacent `char*`

from the last code, I **cannot** do things like

```
  **(str) = 'H';

*(str)[0] = 'H';

str[0][0] = 'H';
```

**except** if I have an **array of char**

```
char str[5][10]; // allocated 5 strings slots, 10 max characters for each
*(str)[0] = 'H';
*(str[0]+1) = 'e';
str[0][2] = 'l';
str[0][3] = 'l';
*((*str)+4 )= 'o';
printf("%s\n", str[0]); // Prints: Hello
```

I can allocate `512` char and just use `12`, I can allocate `1024` char and still need more, I can go **out of memory** if I allocated too much

I've to use **char*** and I need to be able to change the value of **an** `char` like I did in that last **array**

like, let's say I'm building an compiler, text editor...
I need to be able to allocate memory at **runtime** plus check some characters like `';'`

**Or** an `split()` function, which **splits** an `char*` into an array of pointers

- Start copying `char[s]` into `char[n][i] // n = 0, ++i, ++s`
- for each `';'` iteration in `char*`, `i = 0, ++n`
- return `char**`

This can be done easily if I'm working with 2D arrays, but they're not, they're pointers...

How can we **change** the value of a `char` in this **pointer**?

Why can we **read** any `char` in this pointer and not **write** to it?

I don't have a full understanding of pointers yet, Sorry if something is wrong with the code, thanks.

Comment: Fundamental misconception. Pointers **point** to data, you don't `malloc()` just to *create* the pointer. When you `malloc()` an address is returned to a memory that you can use until you `free()`. If you reassign the **pointer variable** then you lose reference to the original pointer and thus you can't free it.

Comment: And ... yes, string literals to which your pointers are pointing are in read only memory so you can't write to them, arrays are not read only of course, and you can write to them within their bounds.

Comment: Further, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc` anyway, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: `str = "hello";` overwrites the pointer obtained from `malloc`, and then you try to write to a string literal.

Comment: You'll have to use strcpy() to copy strings.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: This question is not a duplicate of [String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go) because the OP here is not asking where a string literal goes. As their title indicates, they believe they are writing to an allocated array, so they misunderstand the assignment `str = "Hello"`. So, fundamentally, the question is “What are the semantics of `str = "Hello"`?”

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was trying to mark as duplicate of all the content that is relevant, but honestly it was too hard to find one for the assignment problem. I realize what you say is true, but being a user for a long time and specially only for the [tag:c] tag, I really see the same question over and over, and I wish finding the right duplicates was easier, because IMHO this pollutes SO.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Also, even though the question is not exactly the same, the answer does apply. The OP has doubts about it, so there they would find a complete explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a segfault here

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(512);
str = "hello";
*(str) = 'H'; // Segmentation fault
```

because you are setting `ptr` to point to a string literal, the old value
(returned by `malloc`) is gone. And modifying string literals is undefined behaviour and
in most systems string literal are in read-only memory anyway, so you cannot
modify them. The segfault is the consequence of that.

Note that `str = "hello"` is an assignment, you are copying the address of where
the string literal is stored in memory in the pointer `str`. `str` is now
pointing to the string literal. **But** you haven't done a copy of the
**contents**, for that you need to use a function like `strcpy` or `strncpy`:

```
char* str = malloc(512);
if(str == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    // do not continue
}
strcpy(str, "hello"); // copying the content of the string literal
*(str) = 'H'; // now it works
```

And please note that [you don't have to cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). And don't forget to
check if `malloc` returns `NULL` and to free the memory afterwards.

**edit**

> ```
>    char str[5][10]; // allocated 5 strings slots, 10 max characters for each
>    *(str)[0] = 'H';
>    *(str[0]+1) = 'e';
>    str[0][2] = 'l';
>    str[0][3] = 'l';
>    *((*str)+4 )= 'o';
>    printf("%s\n", str[0]); // Prints: Hello
> ```

Here you have one problem though, you are not setting the `'\0'`-terminating
byte, the `printf` yields an undefined behaviour. The correct code should be:

```
char str[5][10]; // allocated 5 strings slots, 10 max characters for each
*(str)[0] = 'H';
*(str[0]+1) = 'e';
str[0][2] = 'l';
str[0][3] = 'l';
*((*str)+4 )= 'o';
str[0][5] = '\0'; // terminating the string
printf("%s\n", str[0]); // Prints: Hello
```

---

**edit 2**

> How can we **change** the value of an char **in a pointer** in **C**?

The problem with your confusion was that you didn't realize that you lost the
pointer to the `malloc`ed memory block and tryied to modify a string literal
instead.

How can you change the value of a `char` in a pointer?

Like this:

```
char text[] = "This is a long text";
char *ptr = text;
ptr[0] = 't';
```

this works, because `text` has been initialized with the contents of the string
literal. `ptr` is pointing to the start of start of the sequence of characters
stored in `text`, `ptr[0]` allows you to access the first character in the
sequence.

> Why can we **read** any `char` in an pointer and not **write**  to it?

If you don't have wright permission (for example read-only memory) or the
pointer is declared as `const`, then you cannot obviously write a character
through the pointer. But if the pointer points to valid, writeable memory, then
you **can** write a character through the pointer.

Comment: +1 thanks for pointing using strcpy(), I totally forgot `=` which wastes `malloc` or the memory I allocated to a new address, I should've been more careful, Thanks for your answer!

Comment: also yup, I forgot about `'\0'` ty

Comment: @KiraSama don't worry about it, sometimes you do some silly mistake and don't realize it and then you wonder why it seems that the world went crazy. It has happened to me as well.

Answer (score 2):

In order to help with some of the misconceptions you have regarding pointers, I put down a few notes (from a pointers perspective). It's not meant to be facetious or patronizing, but as I went along, telling it from a pointers point of view, just made sense. So let me introduce you to our pointer `p`:

```
char *p;
```

Hello, I am an *uninitialize pointer* to type `char`. I am just a varaible that holds the address to something else as my value. So you can assign any address you want to me without having to allocate anything first. For example,

```
p = "Hello";
```

I now hold the address of the *string-literal* "Hello" as my value. "Hello" itself resides in the .rodata section of the executable (read-only). So you cannot change anything I point to now. But, if the memory I point to is mutable, then you are free to iterate over the characters I point to and make any changes you like, e.g.,

```
char buf[] = "Hello";
p = buf;
```

Now I hold the address of `buf` as my value. Since buf is stored on the stack and can be freely changed, e.g.

```
p[4] = '!';
```

Now the string pointed to by `p` tells you were not to go.

Since I can hold the address to anything else (and do so without violating the *strict aliasing* rule ([C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6)), I can also hold the beginning address to a dynamically allocated block of memory. However, you must take care when I do. In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

That means while I point to a dynamically allocated block, you cannot assign another address to me until you either store the address I point to somewhere else, or `free` the memory I point to. Otherwise, you will have lost the address for the memory I used to point to and it can never be freed again (a memory leak).

I have another important role as a pointer. I provide *pointer arithmetic*. My `type` determines the number of bytes involved when I am incremented, decremented or indexed. Since `sizeof char` is always `1`, any pointer arithmetic on a character type only advances or decrements by `1-byte`, but if I am a type `int`, then the increments or decrements move `4-bytes` at a time, and so on...

When you use me to allocate storage, always use the size of what I point to in determining the size of the allocation. For instance to allocate `100 chars`,

```
p = malloc (100 * sizeof *p);
```

It works the same way if I point to a compound type, e.g.

```
typedef struct {
    char word[100];
    int nvowels;
} list_t;
...

size_t listsize = 100;
list_t *p = malloc (listsize * sizeof *p);
```

If you use my size for allocation instead of trying to take the size of some type, I will prevent you from ever getting it wrong.

So that's pretty much a day-in-the-life-of a pointer. (multiple levels of indirection work the same)

Comment: Sure, it always helps to put yourself in another shoes -- even if the other is just a pointer `:)`

Comment: Nice, it sure was a lot of work, but perhaps we want to go to hell!, how knows ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(512);
str = "hello";
*(str) = 'H'; // Segmentation fault
```

And then you say:

> Well, Is it in Read-Only memory? I'm not sure why that happened but I can change the whole pointer just like I did

Yeah, you *literally changed the whole pointer*. You now made `str` point to read-only memory and totally wasted the memory allocated by `malloc`. Once again, `str = "hello";` does not write data into the memory provided by `malloc`. It just makes `str` point to something else.

Comment: OP may not understand that `str = "hello"` assigns the address of the first character of `"hello"` to `str` rather than assigns “hello” to the contents of the memory currently pointed to by `str`, and this answer does not correct that misunderstanding.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, that's why I made an edit to my answer (and submitted it 4 seconds after you commented).